# Проблема с перебором результатов поиска через LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Пытаюсь написать поиск через LINQ по списку объектов.
Но в строке перебора найденных объектов почему то, не итерируется список.

```
namespace Employee
{
    class Organization
    {

        private readonly List<Employee> _employeeList = new List<Employee>();

        public Organization(List<Employee> employeeList)
        {
            _employeeList = employeeList;
        }

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return _employeeList;
        }

        public List<Employee> FindByFirstName(string FirstName)
        {
            var selectedEmployees = from employee in _employeeList
                                where employee.FirstName == FirstName
                                select _employeeList;

            List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();

            foreach (Employee employee in selectedEmployees)
            {
                result.Add(employee);
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

Студия ругается на строку foreach (Employee employee in selectedEmployees)

> Ошибка    CS0030  Не удается преобразовать тип
> "System.Collections.Generic.List<Employee.Employee>" в
> "Employee.Employee"

Хотя делаю по примеру из статьи.
Подскажите что тут не так?

Comment: `select _employeeList;` => `select employee;` ?

Comment: не проще ли `public List<Employee> FindByFirstName(string FirstName) => _employeeList.Where(e=>e.FirstName == FirstName).ToList();` ?

Comment: я VBшник и редко пользуюсь линком...

Comment: я не осуждаю, я вообще не C# больше не пишу. Просто предлагаю варианты )

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: У `List<T>` есть собственный метод `FindAll`. Проще всего использовать его.